# Numerical resolution of non-linear coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages

I have problem with my code in Mathematica. I have introduced the set of coupled non-linear ODES. This is the resolution part:

```
(*Initial parameters*)
A = 0.5;
a = 0.9;
Ω = 0.24;

(*Initial conditions*)
υ0 = 0.22;
α0 = Pi;
ψ0 = Pi/2;
r0 = 20;
θ0 = Pi/8;
φ0 = 0;

Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"]; \
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
(*Systems to integrate*)

system = {x1'[t] == 
    Eq1[A, a, Ω, x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x2'[t] == 
    Eq2[A, a, Ω, x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x3'[t] == 
    Eq3[A, a, Ω, x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x4'[t] == 
    Eq4[A, a, Ω, x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x5'[t] == 
    Eq5[A, a, Ω, x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x6'[t] == 
    Eq6[A, a, Ω, x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]], 
   x1[0] == υ0, x2[0] == α0, x3[0] == ψ0, 
   x4[0] == r0, x5[0] == θ0, x6[0] == φ0};

sol = NDSolve[system, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {t, 0, 14000}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 22,
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 22];

ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[{x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Cos[x6[t]], x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Sin[x6[t]], 
    x4[t]*Cos[x5[t]]} /. sol], {t, 0, 14000}, PlotPoints -> 10000, 
 ColorFunction -> {Red}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

I receive the following error messages

> `NDSolve::precw`: "The precision of the differential equation ({<<1>>}) is less than \
>   WorkingPrecision (`` 22.` ``)"
>   `NDSolve::ndsz`: At `` t == 140.91450584595810589848638366914914657367`22. ``, step size is \
>   effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

Someone could suggest me how to improve my code? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to `Rationailze` your numbers, like `A = Rationalize[0.5];`. Does that hep?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think it is more connected with the method to be used! :-(

Comment: Please clarify. It you what @user21 suggests for **all four** parameters that are [machine precision](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/MachinePrecisionNumbers.html), the error (it's just a warning, actually) you cite goes away. Probably has to do with the missing code. Problems with code generally requires the code for the problem to be solved. You could try `Rationalize[system]` or `Rationalize[system, 0]`.

Comment: It gives me still the same error, even if I add Rationalize

Comment: I could not reproduce the test cases from the article https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.03380.pdf . Perhaps there is an error in the equations.

Comment: @AlexTrounev it is not possible because the plots have been produced by writing a code in C++. I would like to reproduce them in Mathematica, and I am not able. The paper does not contain error.

Comment: @VDF I checked only part of your equations, but I can not check everything. How did you test the code?

Comment: @AlexTrounev the code has been checked in different ways: (1) comparison with a previous model, (2) comparison in the limiting case of pure gravitation, (3) checking theoretical predictions with trajectories. There have been several cross check to be sure that the published results were correct. My idea is that the NDSolve does not use a correct method to properly integrate the trajectories.

Comment: @VDF Can you post data for one test? I will check.

Comment: These are a data of a simulation where A=0.85, a=0.07, \Omega=0.005, f=100. The initial conditions on the test particle are: r_0=15, \varphi_0=0, \theta_0=pi/4, \nu_0=0.13,\alpha_0=0,\psi_0=pi/2. I do not know how to copy my data. They are too many! :-(

Comment: Try if it is possible to download the data from this link https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/my-drive

Comment: @VDF Just add a picture to your post. I did not find the parameters `f`, `\nu` in your code.

Comment: Check this post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206902/solving-numerically-a-dissipative-non-linear-system-of-coupled-odes?noredirect=1#comment531824_206902

Answer (score 2):

I ran two tests to understand what freezes `NDSolve`. I used a simple code that implements Runge-Kutta 4 orders. As it turned out, `NDSolve` freezes at the moment when the particle descends from the regular trajectory.  In the article on https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.03380v1 , the authors report "Therefore we adapted the highly-accurate core for the integration of photon trajectories used in LSDCode+ [45] to the case of massive particles. The code implements the Runge-Kutta method of the eighth order (the Dorman – Prince method) [46] with an adaptive step." I can advise you not to use `NDSolve` to solve the problem, but to develop your own code. Code for one test

```
(*Useful initial functions*)\[CapitalSigma][r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := 
  r^2 + (a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2;
\[CapitalDelta][r_, a_] := r^2 - 2 M*r + a^2;
\[Rho][r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := 
  r^2 + a^2 + 
   2 M*r*(a*Sin[\[Theta]])^2/\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]];
\[Gamma][\[Upsilon]_] := 1/Sqrt[Abs[(1 - \[Upsilon]^2)]];

(*Useful further functions*)
N2[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := \[CapitalDelta][r, a]/\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]];
Nphi[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -2 M*a*
   r/(\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]);

(*Metric components*)
gtphi[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -4 M*a*r*
   Sin[\[Theta]]^2/\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]];
gphiphi[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := \[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]]^2;
grr[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := \[CapitalSigma][r, 
    a, \[Theta]]/\[CapitalDelta][r, a];
gthth[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := \[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]];
gtt[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -(1 - 2 M*r/\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]);

(*Kinematical quantities*)
AR[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := (M/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
       Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5*\[CapitalDelta][r, 
          a]]))*(\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^2*(r^2 - 
        a^2) + (a*
         Sin[\[Theta]])^2*(r^2*(3*r^2 - 4 M*r + 
           a^2) + (a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2*(r^2 - a^2)));
TR[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := 
  a*M Sin[\[Theta]]*((r^2 + a^2)*(\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]] - 
         2*r^2) - 
      2*r^2*\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]])/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
      Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5]);
KR[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta][r, 
       a]/\[CapitalSigma][r, 
        a, \[Theta]]^5]*(r*\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^2 + 
      M (a*Sin[\[Theta]])^2*(\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]] - 
         2*r^2))/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]);

AT[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -a^2*r M*
   Sin[2*\[Theta]]*(r^2 + a^2)/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
      Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5]);
TT[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := 
  a^2*r M*Sin[2*\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]]*
   Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta][r, a]]/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
      Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5]);
KT[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -Sin[
     2*\[Theta]]*((r^2 + 
         a^2)*(2*a^2*r M*
          Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + \[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^2) + 
      2*a^2*r M*\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]*
       Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(2*\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
      Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5]*Sin[\[Theta]]^2);

(*Impact parameters and emission angles*)
RS = 5/2;(*radius of the emission source*)
b[a_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := -(gtphi[RS, a, \[Theta]] + 
     gphiphi[RS, a, \[Theta]]*\[CapitalOmega])/(gtt[RS, a, \[Theta]] +
     gtphi[RS, a, \[Theta]]*\[CapitalOmega]);
q[a_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 
  If[b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]] != 
    0, (b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*Cot[\[Theta]])^2 - (a*
       Cos[\[Theta]])^2, -(a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2];
\[Beta][r_, a_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 
  ArcCos[b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*
    Sqrt[N2[r, 
       a, \[Theta]]]/(Sqrt[
        gphiphi[r, a, \[Theta]]]*(1 + 
         b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*Nphi[r, a, \[Theta]]))];

(*Factor of the radiation field*)
Rrad[r_, a_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := (r^2 + a^2 - 
      a*b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]])^2 - \[CapitalDelta][r, 
     a]*(q[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]] + (b[
          a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]] - a)^2);
FACT[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  A*(1 + b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*Nphi[r, a, \[Theta]])^2/(N2[
       a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*
      Sqrt[Rrad[r, a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]]);

(*Radiation field components*)
F1[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  FACT[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]]*(1 - \[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]*
      Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, 
         a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]])*(Sin[\[Psi]]*
      Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, 
         a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]] - \[Upsilon]);

F2[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  FACT[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]]*(1 - \[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]*
      Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]])*
   Cos[\[Psi]]*
   Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]]/\[Upsilon];

F3[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  FACT[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]]*(1 - \[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]*
      Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]])*
   Sin[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, 
       a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]]/(\[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]);

(*EQUATIONS OF MOTION*)
Eq1[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := -1/\[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*(Sin[\[Alpha]]*
       Sin[\[Psi]]*(AR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]*TR[r, a, \[Theta]]) + 
      Cos[\[Psi]]*(AT[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]*TT[r, a, \[Theta]])) +
    F1[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]];

Eq2[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]/\[Upsilon]*(Sin[\[Psi]]*(AT[
          r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]^2*TT[r, a, \[Theta]] +
          KT[r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Upsilon]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]]^2) - 
      Sin[\[Alpha]]*
       Cos[\[Psi]]*(AR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]*TR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         KR[r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Upsilon]^2)) + 
   F2[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]];

Eq3[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := -\[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*
    Cos[\[Alpha]]/(\[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]])*(AR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
      2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]*TR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
      KR[r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Upsilon]^2 + 
      KT[r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Upsilon]^2*Cos[\[Psi]]^2*Sin[\[Alpha]]) + 
   F3[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]];

Eq4[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*\[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Alpha]]*
   Sin[\[Psi]]/Sqrt[grr[r, a, \[Theta]]];

Eq5[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*\[Upsilon]*
   Cos[\[Psi]]/Sqrt[gthth[r, a, \[Theta]]];

Eq6[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*\[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]*
    Cos[\[Alpha]]/
     Sqrt[gphiphi[r, a, \[Theta]]] - \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*
    Nphi[r, a, \[Theta]]/Sqrt[N2[r, a, \[Theta]]];
(*Initial parameters*)
A = 85/100;(*These are a data of a simulation where A=0.85,a=0.07, \
\Omega=0.005,f=100. The initial conditions on the test particle \
are:r_0=15, \varphi_0=0, \theta_0=pi/4,\n\
u_0=0.13,\alpha_0=0,\psi_0=pi/2. I do not know how to copy my \
data.They are too many!*)
a = .5;
\[CapitalOmega] = .24;
M = 1;
(*Initial conditions*)
\[Upsilon]0 = .22;
\[Alpha]0 = Pi;
\[Psi]0 = Pi/2;
r0 = 20;
\[Theta]0 = Pi/8;
\[CurlyPhi]0 = 0;


system = {x1'[t] == 
    Eq1[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]], 
   x2'[t] == 
    Eq2[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]], 
   x3'[t] == 
    Eq3[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]], 
   x4'[t] == 
    Eq4[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]], 
   x5'[t] == 
    Eq5[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]], 
   x6'[t] == 
    Eq6[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]], 
   x1[0] == \[Upsilon]0, x2[0] == \[Alpha]0, x3[0] == \[Psi]0, 
   x4[0] == r0, x5[0] == \[Theta]0, x6[0] == \[CurlyPhi]0};
sol = NDSolveValue[system, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {t, 0, 200}];

lst = Table[{x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Cos[x6[t]], x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Sin[x6[t]],
     x4[t]*Cos[x5[t]]}, {t, 0, 132, 1}];
(*RK4*) rk4[f_, variables_, valtinit_, tinit_, tfinal_, nsteps_] := 
  Module[{table, ylist, step, k1, k2, k3, k4},
   step = N[(tfinal - tinit)/(nsteps)];
   ylist = valtinit;

   table = {ylist};
   Table[k1 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, ylist}]; 
    k2 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k1/2 + ylist}];
    k3 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k2/2 + ylist}];
    k4 = step*f /. MapThread[Rule, {variables, k3 + ylist}];
    ylist += 1/6 (k1 + 2 (k2 + k3) + k4);
    AppendTo[table, ylist];
    ylist, nsteps];
   table];


funclist = {Eq1[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], 
   Eq2[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], 
   Eq3[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], 
   Eq4[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], 
   Eq5[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1, x2, x3, x4, x5], 
   Eq6[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]};
initials = {\[Upsilon]0, \[Alpha]0, \[Psi]0, 
   r0, \[Theta]0, \[CurlyPhi]0};
variables = {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6};
init = 0;


final = 2000; nstep = 20000; 
 sol4 = rk4[funclist, variables, initials, init, final, 
   nstep]; // AbsoluteTiming

st = N[(final - init)/(nstep)]; x1 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{i st, sol4[[i, 1]]}, {i, 1, nstep}]]; x2 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{i st, sol4[[i, 2]]}, {i, 1, nstep}]]; x3 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{i st, sol4[[i, 3]]}, {i, 1, nstep}]]; x4 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{i st, sol4[[i, 4]]}, {i, 1, nstep}]]; x5 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{i st, sol4[[i, 5]]}, {i, 1, nstep}]]; x6 = 
 Interpolation[Table[{i st, sol4[[i, 6]]}, {i, 1, nstep}]];

Show[ParametricPlot3D[
   Evaluate[{x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Cos[x6[t]], x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Sin[x6[t]],
      x4[t]*Cos[x5[t]]}], {t, 0, 2000}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotRange -> All], ListPointPlot3D[lst]] // Quiet
```

[image: Figure 1]
How to make `NDSolve` solve this problem? To do this, we define the classical Runge-Kutta method

```
ClassicalRungeKutta /: 
 NDSolve`InitializeMethod[ClassicalRungeKutta, __] := 
 ClassicalRungeKutta[]
ClassicalRungeKutta[___]["Step"[f_, t_, h_, y_, yp_]] := 
  Block[{deltay, k1, k2, k3, k4},
   k1 = yp;
   k2 = f[t + 1/2 h, y + 1/2 h k1];
   k3 = f[t + 1/2 h, y + 1/2 h k2];
   k4 = f[t + h, y + h k3];
   deltay = h (1/6 k1 + 1/3 k2 + 1/3 k3 + 1/6 k4);
   {h, deltay}
   ];
```

Then run three tests with a different combination of parameters

```
sol1 = NDSolve[system, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {t, 0, 2000}, 
    Method -> ClassicalRungeKutta, StartingStepSize -> 1/20, 
    MaxStepSize -> .05, MaxSteps -> 10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming
sol2 = NDSolve[system, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {t, 0, 2000}, 
    Method -> ClassicalRungeKutta, StartingStepSize -> 1/50, 
    MaxStepSize -> .02, MaxSteps -> 10^6]; // AbsoluteTiming
sol3 = NDSolve[system, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {t, 0, 2000}, 
    Method -> ClassicalRungeKutta, StartingStepSize -> 1/100, 
    MaxStepSize -> .01, MaxSteps -> 10^6, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comparing the three solutions, we see that the solution does not converge. This is the main reason `NDSolve` stops at `t=132.` using standard method.
[image: Figure 2]

I found a combination of methods for rk8. Test case

```
A = 0.5;
a = 0.9;
\[CapitalOmega] = 0.24;

(*Initial conditions*)
\[Upsilon]0 = 0.22;
\[Alpha]0 = Pi;
\[Psi]0 = Pi/2;
r0 = 20;
\[Theta]0 = Pi/8;
\[CurlyPhi]0 = 0; tm = 14000;
sol1 = NDSolve[system, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {t, 0, tm}, 
    Method -> {"FixedStep", "StepSize" -> .001, 
      Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
        "DifferenceOrder" -> 8}}]; // AbsoluteTiming
(*Out[]= {380.243, Null}*)

ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[{x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Cos[x6[t]], x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Sin[x6[t]], 
    x4[t]*Cos[x5[t]]} /. sol1], {t, 0, tm}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {x, y, z}]
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: Thank you very much Alex for your help. So, you suggest me to develop my own code. I would have liked to do in Mathematica. Is it not possible to do at all?

Comment: You saw in my code how I used rk4 to solve the problem. Similarly, you can build rk8.

Comment: The main problem of this code is `Eq3`. There is the first term $1 /\sin {\psi}$. When the system approaches $\psi = 0$ then `NDSolve` stops. I checked that rk8 does not go through $\psi = 0$. Interestingly, rk4 goes through $\psi= 0$. This is a classic!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the singularity of `1/x1[t]` that stops `NDSolve[]`, and that is an intrinsic difficulty.

In my experience, often "ImplicitRungeKutta" would be good enough for many stiff problems, as long as the ODE is solvable and analytical (mathematically infinite smooth).

```
sol = NDSolve[system, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {t, 0, 200}, 
              Method -> "ImplicitRungeKutta"];
```

I copy-and-paste your code in both questions, then draw the curve of `x1[t]` with `t` until just before the equations blow up. It is hitting zero.

```
Plot[Evaluate[{x1[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 140.9}]
```

[image]

Note that the `Eq2` code reads

$$
\text{Eq2}[\text{A$\_$},\text{a$\_$},\Omega \_,\upsilon \_,\alpha \_,\psi \_,\text{r$\_$},\theta \_]\text{:=}\gamma [\upsilon ]/\upsilon *(\text{Sin}[\psi ]*(\text{AT}[r,a,\theta ]+2*\upsilon *\text{Cos}[\alpha ]*\text{Sin}[\psi ]{}^{\wedge}2*\text{TT}[r,a,\theta ]+\text{KT}[r,a,\theta ]*\upsilon {}^{\wedge}2*\text{Cos}[\alpha ]{}^{\wedge}2)-\text{Sin}[\alpha ]*\text{Cos}[\psi ]*(\text{AR}[r,a,\theta ]+2*\upsilon *\text{Cos}[\alpha ]*\text{Sin}[\psi ]*\text{TR}[r,a,\theta ]+\text{KR}[r,a,\theta ]*\upsilon {}^{\wedge}2))+\text{F2}[A,a,\Omega ,\upsilon ,\alpha ,\psi ,r,\theta ];
$$

Here is the problem: the term $\gamma [\upsilon ]/\upsilon$ ($\upsilon$ will be replaced by `x1[t]` above) hits the singularity point. That's why ODE solvers complain.

I don't have a good understanding of the ODE system here, but if the singularity is an illusion (say removable by reformulation or coordinate transformation), then there might be a chance to solve it.

Comment: The main problem of this code is `Eq3`. There is the first term 1/sinψ. When the system approaches ψ=0 then `NDSolve` stops.

Comment: @Alex Trounev Ah, I think you are right, it pass through zero several times already.

Comment: Thanks to all. The singularity you talk is removable, because it can be integrated. I should think how to recast it in a way that the apparent singularity is removed. Thanks for your suggestions. I will try to work on it

Comment: I am still not able to solve this issue. The term 1/sin\psi is in all Eq. (3). Probably, I should put an "if", but how?

Comment: I won't feel too bad if something like `If[Abs[\Upsilon]<1/1000,...]` is in the RHS of ODE, especially when you have to. I guess it will be helpful if you explain a bit about why the singularity is removable in the question.