# Solving numerically a dissipative non-linear system of coupled ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

My problem is to integrate a set of couple non-linear and first order ODEs. They are Eqs. (45) -- (50) in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.03380.pdf.

This is the set of differential equations I should integrate:

```
(*Useful initial functions*) 
\[CapitalSigma][r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := r^2 + (a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2;
\[CapitalDelta][r_, a_] := r^2 - 2*r + a^2;
\[Rho][r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := 
  r^2 + a^2 + 
   2*r*(a*Sin[\[Theta]])^2/\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]];
\[Gamma][\[Upsilon]_] := (1 - \[Upsilon]^2)^(-1/2);

(*Useful further functions*) 
N2[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := \[CapitalDelta][r, a]/\[Rho][r, 
    a, \[Theta]];
Nphi[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -2*a*
   r/(\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]);

(*Metric components*) 
gtphi[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -2*a*r*
   Sin[\[Theta]]^2/\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]];
gphiphi[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := \[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]]^2;
grr[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := \[CapitalSigma][r, 
    a, \[Theta]]/\[CapitalDelta][r, a];
gthth[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := \[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]];
gtt[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -(1 - 2*r/\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]);

(*Kinematical quantities*) 
AR[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := (1/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
       Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5*\[CapitalDelta][r, 
          a]]))*(\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^2*(r^2 - 
        a^2) + (a*
         Sin[\[Theta]])^2*(r^2*(3*r^2 - 4*r + 
           a^2) + (a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2*(r^2 - a^2)));
TR[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := 
  a*Sin[\[Theta]]*((r^2 + a^2)*(\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]] - 
         2*r^2) - 
      2*r^2*\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]])/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
      Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5]);
KR[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta][r, 
       a]/\[CapitalSigma][r, 
        a, \[Theta]]^5]*(r*\[CapitalSigma][r, 
         a, \[Theta]]^2 + (a*Sin[\[Theta]])^2 *(\[CapitalSigma][r, 
          a, \[Theta]] - 2*r^2))/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]);

AT[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -a^2*r*
   Sin[2*\[Theta]]*(r^2 + a^2)/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
      Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5]);
TT[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := 
  a^2*r*Sin[2*\[Theta]]*Sin[\[Theta]]*
   Sqrt[\[CapitalDelta][r, a]]/(\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
      Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5]);
KT[r_, a_, \[Theta]_] := -Sin[
     2*\[Theta]]*((r^2 + 
         a^2)*(2*a^2*r*
          Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + \[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^2) + 
      2*a^2*r*\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]*
       Sin[\[Theta]]^2)/(2*\[Rho][r, a, \[Theta]]*
      Sqrt[\[CapitalSigma][r, a, \[Theta]]^5]*Sin[\[Theta]]^2);

(*Impact parameters and emission angles*) 
RS = 2.5; (*radius of the emission source*)

b[a_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := -(gtphi[RS, a, \[Theta]] + 
     gphiphi[RS, a, \[Theta]]*\[CapitalOmega])/(gtt[RS, a, \[Theta]] +
     gtphi[RS, a, \[Theta]]*\[CapitalOmega]); 
q[a_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 
 If[b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]] != 
   0, (b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*Cot[\[Theta]])^2 - (a*
      Cos[\[Theta]])^2, -(a*Cos[\[Theta]])^2];
\[Beta][r_, a_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := 
  ArcCos[b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*
    Sqrt[N2[r, 
       a, \[Theta]]]/(Sqrt[
        gphiphi[r, a, \[Theta]]]*(1 + 
         b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*Nphi[r, a, \[Theta]]))];

(*Factor of the radiation field*) 
Rrad[r_, a_, \[Theta]_, \[CapitalOmega]_] := (r^2 + a^2 - 
      a*b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]])^2 - \[CapitalDelta][r, 
     a]*(q[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]] + (b[
          a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]] - a)^2);
FACT[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  A*(1 + b[a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*Nphi[r, a, \[Theta]])^2/(N2[
       a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]*
      Sqrt[Rrad[r, a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]]);

(*Radiation field components*) 
F1[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  FACT[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]]*(1 - \[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]*
      Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, 
         a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]])*(Sin[\[Psi]]*
      Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, 
         a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]] - \[Upsilon]);

F2[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  FACT[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]]*(1 - \[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]*
      Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]])*
   Cos[\[Psi]]*
   Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]]/\[Upsilon];

F3[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := 
  FACT[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]]*(1 - \[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]*
      Cos[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]])*
   Sin[\[Alpha] - \[Beta][r, 
       a, \[Theta], \[CapitalOmega]]]/(\[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]);

(*EQUATIONS OF MOTION*) 
Eq1[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := -1/\[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*(Sin[\[Alpha]]*
       Sin[\[Psi]]*(AR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]*TR[r, a, \[Theta]]) + 
      Cos[\[Psi]]*(AT[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]*TT[r, a, \[Theta]])) +
    F1[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]];

Eq2[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]/\[Upsilon]*(Sin[\[Psi]]*(AT[
          r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]^2*TT[r, a, \[Theta]] +
          KT[r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Upsilon]^2*Cos[\[Alpha]]^2) - 
      Sin[\[Alpha]]*
       Cos[\[Psi]]*(AR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]*TR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
         KR[r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Upsilon]^2)) + 
   F2[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]];

Eq3[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := -\[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*
    Cos[\[Alpha]]/(\[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]])*(AR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
      2*\[Upsilon]*Cos[\[Alpha]]*Sin[\[Psi]]*TR[r, a, \[Theta]] + 
      KR[r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Upsilon]^2 + 
      KT[r, a, \[Theta]]*\[Upsilon]^2*Cos[\[Psi]]^2*Sin[\[Alpha]]) + 
   F3[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], \[Upsilon], \[Alpha], \[Psi], 
    r, \[Theta]];

Eq4[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*\[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Alpha]]*
   Sin[\[Psi]]/Sqrt[grr[r, a, \[Theta]]];

Eq5[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*\[Upsilon]*
   Cos[\[Psi]]/Sqrt[gthth[r, a, \[Theta]]];

Eq6[A_, a_, \[CapitalOmega]_, \[Upsilon]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Psi]_, 
   r_, \[Theta]_] := \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*\[Upsilon]*Sin[\[Psi]]*
    Cos[\[Alpha]]/
     Sqrt[gphiphi[r, a, \[Theta]]] - \[Gamma][\[Upsilon]]*
    Nphi[r, a, \[Theta]]/Sqrt[N2[r, a, \[Theta]]];
```

This is the method I used to numerically solve this system of ODEs:

```
(*Initial parameters*)
A = 0.5;
a = 0.9;
\[CapitalOmega] = 0.24;

(*Initial conditions*)
\[Upsilon]0 = 0.22;
\[Alpha]0 = Pi;
\[Psi]0 = Pi/2;
r0 = 20;
\[Theta]0 = Pi/8;
\[CurlyPhi]0 = 0;

Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveProblems`"]; \
Needs["DifferentialEquations`NDSolveUtilities`"];
(*Systems to integrate*)

system = {x1'[t] == 
    Eq1[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x2'[t] == 
    Eq2[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x3'[t] == 
    Eq3[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x4'[t] == 
    Eq4[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x5'[t] == 
    Eq5[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]],
   x6'[t] == 
    Eq6[A, a, \[CapitalOmega], x1[t], x2[t], x3[t], x4[t], x5[t]], 
   x1[0] == \[Upsilon]0, x2[0] == \[Alpha]0, x3[0] == \[Psi]0, 
   x4[0] == r0, x5[0] == \[Theta]0, x6[0] == \[CurlyPhi]0};

sol = NDSolve[system
   , {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6}, {t, 0, 14000}, 
   Method -> {"StiffnessSwitching", 
     Method -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", Automatic}}, AccuracyGoal -> 22,
    MaxSteps -> Infinity, PrecisionGoal -> 15, WorkingPrecision -> 22];

ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[{x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Cos[x6[t]], x4[t]*Sin[x5[t]]*Sin[x6[t]], 
    x4[t]*Cos[x5[t]]} /. sol], {t, 0, 14000}, PlotPoints -> 10000, 
 ColorFunction -> {Red}, ImageSize -> 500]
```

I receive message of error, which is

> At t == 140.91450584595810929101802343188260751055`22., step size is \
>   effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected

Could you please help me? Thank you very much.

For further information, please see the images reported down. Thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you include your code in a copiable form rather than in images?  That will make it easier for folks to try to help you.

Comment: VDF, please update your original post to contain all code necessary -  not as images but in a copiable form.

Comment: Dear ChrisK and user21 thank you for your help. I have updated my question. See if it is ok for you. Thanks for your help and suggestions.